# How can i fix MinGW -Wl, --dynamicbase not working properly?

Tags: windows, gcc, segmentation-fault, aslr

I just read about [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), and i found gcc have related flag for ASLR from [here](https://gist.github.com/jrelo/f5c976fdc602688a0fd40288fde6d886). The flag is `-Wl,--dynamicbase`, so i try it with this command `gcc test.c -Wl,--dynamicbase -o test.exe`. I try run it and everything runs well, but when i check for ASLR with [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), it looks like ASLR for my program is turned off. I continue reading and find this flag `-pie -fPIE`, then i try again with this command `gcc test.c -Wl,--dynamicbase -o test.exe -pie -fPIE`, but after i run, the program receive SIGSEGV. I don't know for sure what is the problem. **So could you give me the right flag or what i miss?** My computer support for ASLR, i know it because ProcessExplorer show some process with ASLR turned on. Thanks for your attention.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    puts("lol");
}
```

Comment: `-Wl,--dynamicbase` should work, but you need ld 2.34 or newer.

Comment: so ld 2.34 or newer, my ld is 2.28, Thanks for helpful comment